# azure-pipeline-task-lib attachment limitations

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

i have developed an extension for azure pipeline task.  i'm using the attachments functionality with the code `task.addAttachment(type, fileName, filePath);` to store data and later access it easily.
however, i couldn't find any documentation regarding attachments limitation - in size or number.
are there any limitations on that?  if if so - what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently -> There are no official limitations for this functionality.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/issues/803